# Machine Learning: Digit recognition

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition

I wrote a neural network to recognize hand-written digits a few months ago. The way it worked was I would take the image files, convert them to some standard size (square by the way), and plug them into the neural network with as many input neurons as pixels in the image. The neural network had a single hidden layer with as many neurons as pixels in the image's width (30 or so here) and 10 output neurons which returned 'boolean' values (0 to 1) indicating it's decision.

As I had it trained, it could only get to about 70 percent accuracy. Then I had the idea to instead have 10 neural networks, each with a specialized task of looking for a single digit in the inputs. With this method, I've been able to get each of the nets to function at about 90 percent accuracy.

On a few occasions, I get multiple positives and others, weak confirmations (the right network return .09 for instance instead of 1.0). In these cases, I can't figure out how to get the program to select the right answer because it would involve a complex algorithm of conversion factors between networks and prioritizing certain networks over one another, modeled after their mean accuracies.

My question is: Can I get a neural network to a.) weed out a single, strong positive (<.90) with multiple 'strong' inputs and b). amplify weak positives?

Is this the place for another NN, or should I just focus on refining a (traditionally) programatic selection algorithm?

Comment: For digit recognition It's really overkill to have a whole network for each class. First of all, did you diagnose the accuracy problems (over/underfit) ? Maybe you just didn't train enough ? What kind and amount of data did you use ? MNIST ?

Comment: This is a long-solved problem.  As @FabienBenoit-Koch said, look up the MNIST data base and solution.  It's quite possible that you can simply download a trained model, slap it on your images, get the accuracy you want, and make it home in time for dinner.  Start with MNIST, do the research, and see where it takes you next.

Comment: I know that the way most models do it is probably easier than what I'm trying to do, but the point of the question is more about doing it this for the sake of doing it this way. My question is not how to maximize efficiency. It's "is this problem (what the 2nd neural network seeks to accomplish) beyond a neural network?" Furthermore, what I'm doing is less 'overkill' than it immediately seems. Effectively, I'm increasing the number of hidden layers.

Comment: You should be using a Convolutional Neural Network, that is the start of the art and can easily reach 99% accuracy.